# using rethinkdb to calculate the area of a polygon

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm hoping to do a filter of polygons smaller than a certain area. can this be achieved using rethinkdb without calculating the area beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working with some of my own data, but a small variation of this should work. Here I'm providing a function to filter which calculates the area and returns `true` or `false` depending on it being greated than `REQ_AREA`. You could also create an index that preforms this calculation automatically by passing a anonymous function to `.createIndex('area', function(doc) { ... }` and then doing a `getAll` using that index.

The `.slice` and `prepend`|`appending` is just rotating the x and y coords for simpler multiplication mapping.

Here's out the ReQL area calculation looks like though:

```
r.db('geography').table('area_polygons').filter((doc) => {

  // Retrieve just the points of the polygon
  var coords = doc('polygon').toGeojson()('coordinates').nth(0)

  var x_coords = coords.map((point) => {return point.nth(0)}).coerceTo('array');
  var y_coords = coords.map((point) => {return point.nth(1)}).coerceTo('array');

  // Move item from beginning to end
    y_coords = y_coords.append(y_coords.slice(0,1).nth(0)).deleteAt(0);
  var x = r.map(x_coords, y_coords, (l, r) => { return l.mul(r) }).sum();

  // Reset y and now move first x item to end
  y_coords = y_coords.prepend(y_coords.slice(-1).nth(0)).deleteAt(-1);
  x_coords = x_coords.append(x_coords.slice(0,1).nth(0)).deleteAt(0);
  var y = r.map(x_coords, y_coords, (l, r) => { return l.mul(r) }).sum();

  // Return area
  return x.sub(y).div(2) > REQ_SIZE ? true : false;
})
```